# False converting from lat/long into UTM

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude, c++, utm

Im trying to convert lat/long into UTM, but have some problems in it.
First I get my coordinates in lat and long

```
latitude_wgs84_radians: 0.924593
longitude_wgs84_radians: 0.176054
```

Then Im trying to convert it with `GeographicLib` and get

```
latitude: 185532
longitude: 102251
```

which is false, 'cause it should be near

```
575983.09
5869562.84
```

Then I was trying to correct my code and get after converting to UTM

```
latitude: 568000 
longitud: 5.866e+06 //this one is not correct
```

at least, my code

```
double lat = latitude_wgs84_radians * 180 / M_PI;
double lon = longitude_wgs84_radians * 180 / M_PI;
int zone;
bool northp;
double x, y;
UTMUPS::Forward(lat, lon, zone, northp, x, y);
```

Comment: What is lat/lon (or M_PI)?  I get lat = 52.97527666734, lon = 10.0871511663962. If I assume WGS84, and zone 32N (AKA EPSG:32632), I get  572999.5882819915, 5870073.21873018 using a different software package (Esri).

Comment: @mkennedy `latitude: 568000 longitud: 5.866e+06`, this are the converted coordinates from lat/long to UTM, but the values are not correct.

Comment: No, those are projected coordinates in UTM. They're no longer latitude and longitude values but x (easting) and y (northing) values.